# jquery - remove a class that has a double dash

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using select2 widget from yii2. And I wanted to removed the specific class because as the example provided by the select2 is that it needs a model to run, and I dont know how to handle that way. And also because i don't have enough time to apply the way that select2 widget implements in yii2.

Since i'm new from yii2 and i'm creating my way to have a dropdown search, which i've really wanted the way that the select2 works.

Html:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--krajee select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr"></span>
```

Jquery:

```
$('span .select2').removeClass('select2-container--focus');
```

How can I remove this class `select2-container--focus` from span?
Or is there any other way to remove that class using jquery.

Comment: Do you want to remove  all classes with a double hash ?

Comment: nope... I've wanted to remove this class "select2-container--below" and "select2-container--focus"

Comment: because i could not remove the class that have double dash.

Comment: That is because the classes are being re-applied dynamically by the Select2 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a extra space in `span .select2`

use

```
$('span.select2').removeClass('select2-container--focus');
```

```js
$('#remove').click(function() {
   $('span.select2').removeClass('select2-container--focus');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--krajee select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr">
  Some thing in span
</span>
<button id="remove">removeClass</button>
```

Comment: Please try not to link to off-site resources. You can use the code snippet tools in SO to do your demo.

Comment: It doen't work its becase as @Soviut said. It will always reapply that class because i'm using a select2 widget.

Comment: @CoD_Arkalodia_3 the click event is just an example here. You could try applying it to your instance of Select2.focus.

Comment: @CoD_Arkalodia_3 the original question you had was on removing a class form an element and the impact of having -- on the class name. Included is a simple deom on how to do that.

Comment: @Soviut yeah..I also creating my own click event. But it doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly how you remove a class using jQuery. However, [that class is being re-applied by Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/062c6c3af5f0f39794c34c0a343a3857e587cc97/src/js/select2/core.js#L489), so each time you focus on it, or something it relates to, it will re-apply the class.

There are plenty of ways you can brute force remove the class using javascript, but none of them will work perfectly and may introduce weird behaviour or visual artifacts like flickering. The most likely candidate for a code solution would be to hook into the `Select2.focus` event and hope that your event handler triggers after their's does.

Assuming you just want to prevent the class from styling the element, you could override the class with your own styles, or [override the theme](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#themes-templating-responsive-design).

Comment: yeah.. i've experience flickering. But is there any alternative way to remove  that specific class?

Comment: Why do you need to remove it? You should update your question and explain your reason since there may be a better alternative.

Comment: Based on your updated question, just read the docs and learn to use Select2 properly. Fighting it is not going to be easier; This whole Q&A is a testament to that.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for the help.